# React props type with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm using a recipe that is often recommended:

```
interface IFooProps extends React.Props<Foo> {
    bar: string;
}

export class Foo extends React.Component<IFooProps, {}> {
    render() {
        return <p className={this.props.bar}>{this.props.children}<p>
    }
}
```

However, `React.Props` is marked as deprecated with React 16 and appropriate `@types/react`.

What is the right way to do this?

*This is primarily TypeScript types question, and `prop-types` (`React.PropTypes`) runtime types aren't applicable here*.

Comment: by using `prop-types` package - have you tried googling your question? it has tons of answers...

Comment: Did you check the question? It applies to TypeScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[As it's suggested in `@types/react`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/242fcd3080c74d4b1015f7a94c6a63a9928052f0/types/react/index.d.ts#L609-L626), `React.Props` is deprecated in favour of [`React.ClassAttributes`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/242fcd3080c74d4b1015f7a94c6a63a9928052f0/types/react/index.d.ts#L83-L88) that has `key` and `ref` properties, so it should be:

```
interface IFooProps extends React.ClassAttributes<Foo> {
    bar: string;
}
```

Since component class augments `IFooProps` with [`children` property](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/242fcd3080c74d4b1015f7a94c6a63a9928052f0/types/react/index.d.ts#L299), `this.props.children` complies with `props` type.